# Linear Algebra need help with proof please over eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that if x and y are distinct eigenvalues of an nxn matrix A, then the intersection of eigenspaces is the 0 vector. How can I prove this?

Comment: Hint: try a proof by contradiction.  What if the intersection of the eigenspaces isn't zero?

Comment: but doesn't it have to be 0?

Comment: @user123204:  though your hunch that $w = 0$ may be correct, you don't *know* this for a fact until a proof is presented.  Now, *a priori*, either $w = 0$ or $w \ne 0$.  So we rule out the case $w \ne 0$ by showing it's logical consequence is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $V_x$ is the $x$-eigenspace, and $V_y$ is the $y$-eigenspace, and $0 \ne w \in V_x \cap V_y$.  Then since $w \in V_x$, $Aw = xw$.  Likewise $w \in V_y$, so $Aw = yw$.  Then $xw = yw$ so $(x - y)w = 0$.  But $x \ne y$, so $x - y \ne 0$.  Then multiplying through by $(x - y)^{-1}$ yields $w = 0$, contradicting the assumption that $w \ne 0$.  Thus $0$ is the only element of $V_x \cap V_y$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a short cut for the proof right above my answer. You can simply say $Aw=xw=yw$ but this is true if and only if $w=0$ because $x$ is not equal to $y$.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say x is not equal to y

Comment: You can edit your answer (using the link "edit" right below it). I have edited it for you now, anyway.